# Position canvas drawings to the left top corner of container dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm creating a map dynamically from a json file but the drawings end up out of screen because of the x,y. What I wanted to do is to move the all drawings to closer to the left and top of the map element that contains the drawing.

I tried couple of things like playing with the top in css but then the div goes on top of other controls. The other idea is to modify the existing coordinates and do some math with it but I want to know if there is a better approach. 
Here what I have

```
var c=[];
c.push(["valu1",120,240]);
c.push(["valu1",130,240]);
c.push(["valu2",120,250]);
c.push(["valu3",130,250]);
c.push(["valu4",120,245]);
c.push(["valu5",130,245]);
```

//7k more rows will be here.

```
$("#refresh").on("click",function(){
    getdata();
});


function getdata()
{
    for (var i in c) {

        var x =   c[i][1]
        var y = c[i][2]
        Paint(x,y);

}

}

function Paint(x, y) {
    var ctx, cv;
    cv = document.getElementById('map');
    ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#666699';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeRect(x, y, 10, 5);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

notice the first row x = 120. what I would like to move closer to the top of my element.

here is the jsfiddle. 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/czcz/h5g26Ljr/)

Comment: If you are passing `120, 240` as the coordinates, it does look alright to me. What exactly do you mean by `move closer to the top of my element`? Do you want the table to start at `0,0`? In that case  you can subtract a specific amount from all the cells to get it to align with the top.

Comment: I'm doing that at the moment but I have different maps with different values and some maps are closer to the top others are way at the bottom.

Comment: One solution can be interpolating the value that is closest to the top to `0` by subtracting say `x` pixels. Subtract `x` from all the others and get them closer to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an implementation that displaces the points toward the upper left as far as possible. If the map is still too large, it will have to be scaled to fit the canvas.

Note that I have changed some variable names and streamlined the code in various places. To make the canvas larger, see the parameters at the beginning of the `start()` function.

```js
var data = [
    ["a", 120, 240],
    ["b", 130, 240],
    ["c", 120, 250],
    ["d", 130, 250],
    ["e", 120, 245],
    ["f", 130, 245]
];  

function drawBox(context, x, y, width, height) {
    context.strokeStyle = '#666699';
    context.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
}

function start() {
    // The following are the display parameters. Set them to your liking.
    var boxWidth = 10, boxHeight = 5, lineWidth = 2,
        canvasWidth = 800, canvasHeight = 600;  // Canvas dimensions.

    var container = document.getElementById('container'),
        canvas = container.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    container.style.width = canvasWidth + 'px';
    container.style.height = canvasHeight + 'px';

    var n = data.length,
        minX = data[0][1],
        minY = data[0][2];
    for (var i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        var x = data[i][1],
            y = data[i][2];
        if (x < minX) {
            minX = x;
        }
        if (y < minY) {
            minY = y;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        var x = data[i][1], y = data[i][2],
            X = lineWidth + x - minX,  // Displace the points to upper right.
            Y = lineWidth + y - minY;  // Add padding to avoid clipping lines.
        drawBox(context, X, Y, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }
}

window.onload = start;
```

```css
#container {
    border: 3px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><canvas></canvas></div>
```